# Calling method to add to ArrayList

Tags: arraylist

The user initially needs to select option "a" to add wardrobe locations where they will eventually place their outfits. Their info is put into an arraylist without overwriting. This part works.

Then they can select option b, where it searches the arraylist for the location based on floor number. If the floor number is found, the user enters the outfit type, which is then sent to an arraylist in the Location class. This is where I'm stuck. It seems to add it to the arraylist, but if I want to go back and add another outfit to that floor number's wardrobe location, it overwrites it rather than adds to it.

I need it to be able to add the user's outfit to the arraylist and allow the user to go back, input the same floor number for option b, and add another outfit in addition to the initial outfit added (and doesn't overwrite).

My code is below.

Main method:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                        int selection;
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String firstInput;
    int floorNumber;
    String roomLocation;
    boolean loop;
    boolean bigLoop;
    ArrayList<Location> locationArr = new ArrayList<Location>();   

do{
bigLoop = true;
do{

loop = true;
    System.out.println("Select from the following:");
    System.out.println("a. Add wardrobe location");
    System.out.println("b. Add outfit to the wardrobe location");
    firstInput = console.nextLine();

    if (firstInput.equals("a")) {
            System.out.println("Please enter which floor your wardrobe is located on:");
            floorNumber = console.nextInt();
            console.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter room your wardrobe is located in (e.g. living room, bedroom, etc.):");
            roomLocation = console.nextLine();  
            Location currLocation = new Location(floorNumber, roomLocation);    
            locationArr.add(currLocation);
            }
    if (firstInput.equals("b")){
       loop = false;}      
} while (loop == true);

do {
loop = true;
String outfitType;
System.out.println("Please enter the floor number:");
floorNumber = console.nextInt();
console.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < locationArr.size(); i++){
           if (locationArr.get(i).getFloorNumber() == floorNumber) {
               Location currLocation = new Location(locationArr.get(i).getFloorNumber(),locationArr.get(i).getRoomLocation());
               i = locationArr.size();
               System.out.println("Please enter the type of outfit to put in the wardrobe (e.g. dress, suit, etc.):");
               outfitType = console.nextLine();
               String newOutfit = outfitType;
               currLocation.addOutfit(newOutfit);
               loop = false;
            }
}
} while (loop == true);
    } while (bigLoop == true);
    }
}
```

Location class

```
public class Location {
private final int flooorNumber;
private final String rooomLocation;
private final ArrayList<String> clothesInWardrobe = new ArrayList<String>();

public Location(int floorNumber, String roomLocation) {
     this.flooorNumber = floorNumber;
     this.rooomLocation = roomLocation;
}
    public int getFloorNumber(){
        return flooorNumber;
}
    public String getRoomLocation(){
        return rooomLocation;
}
    public int addOutfit(String outfit){
        clothesInWardrobe.add(outfit);
        //the next two lines just test to see if it adds to or overwrites the arraylist
        for (String testToSeeIfItWorks : clothesInWardrobe) {
        System.out.println("In Wardrobe = " + testToSeeIfItWorks);}
        return clothesInWardrobe.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile... `Locations` and `getroomLocation` are wrong.

Comment: @Bifz Thanks for catching that. I changed that variable name last minute and unwisely didn't test it before pasting the code on here. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're creating a new instance of the Location at the position i.

```
           Location currLocation = new Location(locationArr.get(i).getFloorNumber(),locationArr.get(i).getroomLocation(),locationArr.get(i).getWardrobeLocation());
```

Since you don't pass old wardrobe to that location, new ArrayList of wardrobe is being created.
You should use an existing location there instead of creating a new one.

```
Location currLocation = locationArr.get(i);
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.